# How to classify data to different levels?

Tags: r

R.3.3.2

Imagine a vector

```
a <- c(3,2,5,6,7,8,2,9)
```

I want to classify `a` as `less or equal than 4` and `greater than 4`.

When I use `table(a)`

I need to get result like:

```
less or equal than 4          greater than 4

3                               5
```

How to get this result? Any advices? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `table(ifelse(a<=4, "less or equal to 4", "greater than 4"))` i wanted to post, but its just the short version of Roman´s earlier posted solution,....maybe its of use anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the `cut` function in combination with `table`:

```
table(cut(a, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, Inf), 
          labels = c('less and equal than 4','greater than 4'))
      )
```

which gives:

```
less and equal than 4        greater than 4 
                    3                     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
table(a>4)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You could find which value belongs to which group and count the number of values in that group.

```
a <- c(3,2,5,6,7,8,2,9)
x <- data.frame(a, test = a <= 4,
                txt = ifelse(a <= 4, "less or equal to 4", "greater than 4"))
aggregate(a ~ test, data = x, length)

   test a
1 FALSE 5
2  TRUE 3

aggregate(a ~ txt, data = x, FUN = length)

                 txt a
1     greater than 4 5
2 less or equal to 4 3
```

And a third option.

```
table(x$txt)

greater than 4 less or equal to 4 
                 5                  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little bit nicer approach using piping `%>%`, based on @Jaap answer.

Dummy data:

```
a <- c(3,2,5,6,7,8,2,9)

# combine functions using pipes  %>% 

a %>%
  cut(breaks = c(-Inf, 4, Inf),
      labels = c('less and equal than 4','greater than 4')) %>%
  table
```

Which gives results with labels:

```
less and equal than 4        greater than 4 
                    3                     5
```

---

If you wish to have proportion table instead, add `prop.table` at the end of pipes:

```
a %>%
  cut(breaks = c(-Inf, 4, Inf),
      labels = c('less and equal than 4','greater than 4')) %>%
  table %>%
  prop.table  # this was added
```

Which gives as result:

```
less and equal than 4        greater than 4 
                0.375                 0.625
```